# Force python to not output a float in standard form / scientific notation / exponential form

Tags: python

So this works fine:

```
>>> float(1.0e-1)
0.10000000000000001
```

But when dealing with a larger number, it won't print:

```
>>> float(1.0e-9)
1.0000000000000001e-09
```

Is there a way to force this?  Maybe using numpy or something.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
print '{0:.10f}'.format(1.0e-9)
```

[String formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) in the documentation.

Comment: Doesn't work before Python 2.6 (which is not a big deal, but you should have mentioned it).  More seriously, this fixes the number of digits after the decimal point, which is probably not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 11):

Everyone suggesting the use of the `f` string format code is implicitly assuming that it's okay to fix the number of digits after the decimal point.  That seems like a very shaky assumption to me.  However, if you don't make that assumption, there is no built-in mechanism to do what you want. This is the best hack I came up with when faced with a similar problem (in a PDF generator -- numbers in PDF can't use exponential notation). You probably want to take all the `b`s off the strings, and there may be other Python3-isms in here.

```
_ftod_r = re.compile(
    br'^(-?)([0-9]*)(?:\.([0-9]*))?(?:[eE]([+-][0-9]+))?$')
def ftod(f):
    """Print a floating-point number in the format expected by PDF:
    as short as possible, no exponential notation."""
    s = bytes(str(f), 'ascii')
    m = _ftod_r.match(s)
    if not m:
        raise RuntimeError("unexpected floating point number format: {!a}"
                           .format(s))
    sign = m.group(1)
    intpart = m.group(2)
    fractpart = m.group(3)
    exponent = m.group(4)
    if ((intpart is None or intpart == b'') and
        (fractpart is None or fractpart == b'')):
        raise RuntimeError("unexpected floating point number format: {!a}"
                           .format(s))

    # strip leading and trailing zeros
    if intpart is None: intpart = b''
    else: intpart = intpart.lstrip(b'0')
    if fractpart is None: fractpart = b''
    else: fractpart = fractpart.rstrip(b'0')

    if intpart == b'' and fractpart == b'':
        # zero or negative zero; negative zero is not useful in PDF
        # we can ignore the exponent in this case
        return b'0'

    # convert exponent to a decimal point shift
    elif exponent is not None:
        exponent = int(exponent)
        exponent += len(intpart)
        digits = intpart + fractpart
        if exponent <= 0:
            return sign + b'.' + b'0'*(-exponent) + digits
        elif exponent >= len(digits):
            return sign + digits + b'0'*(exponent - len(digits))
        else:
            return sign + digits[:exponent] + b'.' + digits[exponent:]

    # no exponent, just reassemble the number
    elif fractpart == b'':
        return sign + intpart # no need for trailing dot
    else:
        return sign + intpart + b'.' + fractpart
```

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty standard print formatting, specifically for a float:

```
print "%.9f" % 1.0e-9
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's zwol's answer simplified and converted to standard python format:

```
import re
def format_float_in_standard_form(f):
    s = str(f)
    m = re.fullmatch(r'(-?)(\d)(?:\.(\d+))?e([+-]\d+)', s)
    if not m:
        return s
    sign, intpart, fractpart, exponent = m.groups('')
    exponent = int(exponent) + 1
    digits = intpart + fractpart
    if exponent < 0:
        return sign + '0.' + '0'*(-exponent) + digits
    exponent -= len(digits)
    return sign + digits + '0'*exponent + '.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a
1.0000000000000001e-09
>>> print "heres is a small number %1.9f" %a
heres is a small number 0.000000001
>>> print "heres is a small number %1.13f" %a
heres is a small number 0.0000000010000
>>> b
11232310000000.0
>>> print "heres is a big number %1.9f" %b
heres is a big number 11232310000000.000000000
>>> print "heres is a big number %1.1f" %b
heres is a big number 11232310000000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use %e when printing your number:

```
>>> a = 0.1234567
>>> print 'My number is %.7e'%a
My number 1.2345670e-01
```

If you use %g it will automatically choose the best visualization for you:

```
>>> print 'My number is %.7g'%a
My number is 0.1234567
```