# formatted printing of the exponent of a double in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, formatting

Are there any means by which one could tell Python 2.x/3.x to always use 3 digits for the exponent when printing a float (==IEEE754 double precision) in scientific format using the "E" format specifier (or another one)?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345795/force-python-to-not-output-a-float-in-standard-form-scientific-notation-expo) cover what you need?  I'm the one who tagged this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Prune: No, because they want to format the exponent, not the mantissa.

Comment: The answer from panda-34 parses the output string and extracts the exponent (as well as the other parts of the representation).  From here, OP can build any desired format from the parts -- and the given answers provide most of those parts.

Comment: @Prune: thanks for bringing a workaround for the problem to my attention.

Comment: I don't see the "answer from panda-34," @Prune

Comment: That answer seems to have been deleted in the 2.5 years intervening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, the width and precision of the format specifier only affect presentation of the mantissa. You will need to post-process the string if you want to affect the exponent.